# kafka consumer client in java can't reconnect to kubernetes kafka brokers after all of kafka-pods are upgraded

Tags: java, kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I use spring-kafka(2.2.4.RELEASE) to consume message from kafka-server. 
Both kafka clients and servers are deployed in k8s clusters. 
Normally, it is ok to produce and consume messages  on kafka brokers.
But kafka clients can't reconnect to brokers when kafka-brokers are upgraded.

As I know, kafka clients reconnection has a bug when `bootstrap-servers` is virtual ip( [detail is here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/7288)). My problem is alike the vip bug.

In my situation, `bootstrap-servers` address is k8s **kafka service name**:port, and when kafka-brokers are upgraded, the **real ip** corresponding to the **kafka servcie name** will change. 
So kafka client will never reconnect successfully.
How can I fix this?

#### Environment

- kubectl version

```sh
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.10", GitCommit:"098570796b32895c38a9a1c9286425fb1ececa18", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-02T17:19:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.10", GitCommit:"098570796b32895c38a9a1c9286425fb1ececa18", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-02T17:11:51Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

- kafka version: kafka_2.12-2.3.1
- kafka deloyment info:

```sh
> kubectl get svc -o wide -nbingotestdev|grep kafkadev
kafkadev                ClusterIP   None            <none>        9091/TCP                          1y        app=kafkadev
kafkadev-out            NodePort    10.68.206.93    <none>        9091:37142/TCP                    257d      app=kafkadev

> kubectl get pod -o wide -nbingotestdev|grep kafkadev
kafkadev-0                               1/1       Running             0          15h       172.20.10.59    10.171.113.45
kafkadev-1                               1/1       Running             0          15h       172.20.13.95    10.171.113.33
kafkadev-2                               1/1       Running             0          15h       172.20.2.173    10.171.113.62
```

- kafka client configuration：

  - version1:`bootstrap-servers = kafkadev:9091`
  - version2:`bootstrap-servers = 10.68.206.93:9091`
  - both work successfully when kafka servers are ok and reconnect failed after kafka server pods are upgraded.

Comment: How exactly you point clients  to server? Do you use Headless services or something else? What is your setup?

Comment: @Nick    configuration in `application.propterties ` like this: `bootstrap.servers=kafkadev:9091`, and  it will be passed to DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to ensure that you always have a statically assigned IP set that gets returned as the advertised listeners when the consumers fetch the bootstrap servers, whether that be via an external DNS service or using k8s api client directly to inspect the running Kafka services, then fetch all addresses to build up your bootstrap-server string

Comment: How to fetch `a statically assigned IP set`? As I know, the ip which is generated by k8s  is ephemeral and always changed after pods are upgraded especially for stateful sets.

Comment: By Static I mostly mean that the broker ID doesn't change. Have you looked at how the Confluent Helm Charts or Strimzi expose the brokers to the clients?

Comment: We didn't use both.  We build kafka images from `kafka_2.12-2.3.1` and delopy a kafka service as a stateful set.

Comment: Why build you own? I'm pretty sure the Strimzi Kafka operator supports statefulset deployments

Comment: emm, we want to add some acl when installing.  I think I can't get `a statically assigned IP set` from `kafakdev` service name, even when I use `Strimzi Kafka`. 
I think the key is `stateful deployments` generates ephemeral ip for service name.

Comment: ACLs work there too https://strimzi.io/docs/master/#assembly-getting-started-user-operator-str

Comment: The problem is about kafka-clients. I think the problem is also there even after using `Strimzi Kafka`. I want to fix this in current enviroments.

Comment: *You think?* Why not **try it**? Upgrades are actually taken into account by the k8s operator and external listeners are configurable too https://strimzi.io/docs/master/#assembly-configuring-kafka-broker-listeners-deployment-configuration-kafka and if you still don't want to use it, then it's all open source and you can copy the same ideas

Comment: Personally, I will try it. But currently we have deployed those docker-images, and I'm not k8s operator.  As a  Java developer, I want to fix the problem  just in kafka-client side.

Comment: Kafka containers are all the same. Backup the broker logs. Move them over. Should still work exactly the same

Comment: `Srimzi Kafka` create a new k8s kind called `kafka` and expose static ip for clients which will solve the problem. But our team's k8s operator refusd to update kafka images. I should fix the problem in kafka client side.

Comment: Does this help? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-302+-+Enable+Kafka+clients+to+use+all+DNS+resolved+IP+addresses

Comment: ok, I will try to add the parameter. Thanks for your  patient help. If this does not work, I will try to get inner kafka-client status (by reflection or current consumer  api) and decide whether the client should be restarted.